# Observable implicitly unsubscribe in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, observable, unsubscribe

I'm working with observables, and my observable unsubscribed implicitly. But I don't want to unsubscribe at all.

I've created a gallery, where i display images using but there are other tabs as well. As you see in the image.

[image]

When I switch to some other tab. And switch back to gallery tab all images are gone.

here's the code

```
ngOnInit()
  {
    console.log('sp gallery on init');
    // getting images model i.e. id, name desc, content

/****************************This is the observable******************************/

    this.dispImgsSubs = this.galleryService.displayImages.subscribe((displayImages: Array<SPGalleryImagesModel>) =>
    {
      console.log('sp gallery display images on init');

      // adding new images to array
      this.imageModel = this.imageModel.concat(displayImages);

      // re-assigning ids to newest data
      this.imageModel = this.reAssigningIds(this.imageModel, 0);
      console.log(this.imageModel);

      this.isGalleryFromBackend = false;
    });

    if(this.isGalleryFromBackend)
      this.backendService.getSP().subscribe(spData => {

        console.log(spData.locations[0].gallery);
        this.imageModel = spData.locations[0].gallery;
      });
  }
```

here's **gallery service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild,  Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { BackendService } from './backend.service';
import { SPGalleryImagesModel } from '../components/models/sp-profile-gallery-images.model';

@Injectable()
export class GalleryService {

  // emit shorten file path to gallery onChange()
  @Output() filename =  new EventEmitter<SPGalleryImagesModel[]>();

  // emit images array to display in gallery ngOnInit()
  @Output() displayImages = new EventEmitter<SPGalleryImagesModel[]>();

  constructor(private backendService: BackendService) { }

  // adding new images
  addImages(newImages)
  {
    console.log('add images');

    // for uploading to server
    let uploadImages = new Array<SPGalleryImagesModel>();

    //iterating through new images array
    for (let i = 0, img; img = newImages[i]; i++)
    {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      let image = new SPGalleryImagesModel();

      image.name = img.name;
      image.index = i;
      // check whether file is of image format
      if(img.type != 'image/jpeg' && img.type != 'image/jpg' && img.type != 'image/png')
        alert('Only images are supported!');
      else
      {
        image.type = img.type
        // getting image base64 string
        reader.onload = () => image.content = reader.result;

        // converting image to base64 string
        reader.readAsDataURL(img);

        uploadImages.push(image);

        // condition applied so that inner statements run only one time
        if(i == newImages.length - 1)
        {
          reader.onloadend = () =>
          {
            // uploading images
            this.uploadBase64(uploadImages);

            // emitting images array to display in gallery
            this.displayImages.emit(uploadImages);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  uploadBase64(images: Array<SPGalleryImagesModel>)
  {
    let count: number = 0;

    // to send image shorten path to gallery onChange()
    let imagespath:SPGalleryImagesModel[] = [];

    // iterating image to upload a single instance at a time
    for(let image in images)
    {
      // model for uploading image
      let imageFile = new SPGalleryImagesModel();

      // data to send to gallery onChange()
      let imageData = new SPGalleryImagesModel();

      // adding image data to model
      imageFile.name = images[image].name;
      imageFile.content = images[image].content;
      imageFile.type = images[image].type;
      // uploading image
      console.log('try to upload', imageFile)
      this.backendService.uploadBase64({content:imageFile.content, type: imageFile.type}).subscribe(res =>
      {
        console.log('uploading');

        // getting id and filename (shorten image path)
        imageData.index = +image;
        imageData.filename = res.path;

        // pushing data to array
        imagespath.push(imageData);

        //applying condition so that inner statement executed only once
        if(count == images.length - 1)
          // emitting data (filename, id) to gallery onChange
          this.filename.emit(imagespath);

        count++;
      });
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you see this message "sp gallery on init" multiple times when when you switch tabs ?

Comment: @ibenjelloun yes...every time i switched to gallery tab **sp gallery on init** message appears. But the message **sp gallery display images on init** appears only when I add images.

Comment: That means that your tabs system create a new component each time you switch tab. When you switch and switch back, it feels like the same tab but its an all new component.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to unsubscribe?

Comment: @Baruch So that, when I switch back to gallery, images still appear.

Comment: Instead of using 'EventEmitter', please use Behavior Subject that will return the last accessed values.

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya Ok, let me try.

Comment: Not unsubscribing is bad practice. You should have the data gathering in `ngOnInit` and unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy`. You could also keep the data in memory through a service.

Comment: @baruch i got it...thanks